# How do I use CreateView with a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-views

I get an error in my class AuthorCreateForm when I submit my form.
NameError
self is not defined

How do I use a CreateForm?

I have created a class in my Author.py file

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView
from books.models import Author, Publisher, Book
from books.forms import AuthorForm

class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    objAuthorForm = AuthorForm(self.request.POST)

    if(objAuthorForm.save()):
        success = "Form saved!"
    else:
        error = "There was an error!"
```

and I have a html template which submits to /Author/Create

and I have the following line in my urls.py

```
('^authors/create/$', Author.AuthorCreateView.as_view()),
```

I render the form at this URL

```
('^authors/new/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="author_new.html")),
```

I find the class based views confusing, does anyone have a good tutorial on how to use it for CRUD operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 198, accepted):

What you have is a python error -- `self` is not defined. `self` is generally what refers to the class instance itself on class methods.

Anyways, I agree, it's brand spanking new and not as documented. I think looking at the source is absolutely key at this point.

To get comfortable with class based views, I'd start by subclassing `django.views.generic.base.View`, which implements only a few methods, namely attempting to call a function on the class based on the request method (post, get, head, - look at source).

For example, here's the first step to replace view functions with the new view classes:

```
class MyClassBasedView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # behave exactly like old style views
        # except this is called only on get request
        return http.HttpResponse("Get")

    def post(self, request):
        return http.HttpResponse("Post")

(r'^foobar/$', MyClassBasedView.as_view())
```

**Back to your specific question:**

All `TemplateView.as_view()` does is render the template - `CreateView` is a combination of several other classes that handle `ModelForms` and template rendering (`TemplateView`).

So, for a very basic example, [look to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) for what class `mixins` are used by `CreateView`.

We see it implements `TemplateResponseMixin`, `ModelFormMixin`, and `ProcessFormView`, each containing a list of methods for those classes.

---

### The most basic CreateView

At the most basic level, provide `CreateView`'s `ModelFormMixin` with the model or custom ModelForm class [as documented here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#modelformmixin)

Your `CreateView` class would look something like the following

```
class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = AuthorForm
    template_name = 'author_new.html'
    success_url = 'success'
```

With those 3 core attributes set, call it in your URLs.

```
('^authors/create/$', Author.AuthorCreateView.as_view()),
```

Render the page and you'll see your ModelForm passed to the template as `form`, handling the form validation step (passing in `request.POST` / re-render if invalid), as well as calling `form.save()` and redirecting to the `success_url`.

---

### Start overriding the class methods

To customize behavior, start overriding the methods documented for the `mixins`.

Remember that you simply need to return an `HttpResponse` from one of these methods just like any regular view function.

Example overriding `form_invalid` documented in `ModelFormMixin`:

```
class AuthorCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = AuthorForm
    template_name = 'author_new.html'
    success_url = 'success'

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return http.HttpResponse("form is invalid.. this is just an HttpResponse object")
```

---

This per-method overriding starts becoming extremely useful as your forms grow more advanced and ultimately lets you build huge forms with a handful of lines of code, overriding only what is necessary.

Say you want to pass your form custom parameters such as the `request` object (very common if you need access to the user in the form): you merely need to override `get_form_kwargs`.

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # pass "user" keyword argument with the current user to your form
        kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Class based views are a shining example of smart class usage. It gave me a great intro towards building my own mixins for views and python classes in general. It is saving countless hours.

Wow this got long. To think it started as a mere URL to the docs comment :)

Comment: The organization allowed by classes is just awesome! I don't know why I never created a class view in the first place.

Comment: An example of how to unpack the extra `kwargs` on the `forms.py` end is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806224/sending-request-user-object-to-modelform-from-class-based-generic-view-in-django).