# Sending request.user object to ModelForm from class based generic view in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

So, my goal is to be able to filter a ModelChoiceField queryset in my ModelForm to only include Places that request.user has created.

My ModelForm is simply:

```
class PlaceEventForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

I'd like to be able to add something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PlaceEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['place'].queryset = Place.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to access the request in the ModelForm.

My View is like so:

```
class PlaceEventFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = PlaceEventForm
    template_name = 'events/event_create.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PlaceEventFormView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm not sure if this is even close to what I should do, but I tried:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(PlaceEventFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'place_user': self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

But I got the error: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'place_user'

Any ideas on this one?  Or can anyone think of a way to filter my ModelChoiceField in the view without needing to pass my request to the ModelForm?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to pop key `user` from `kwargs` in `PlaceEventForm.__init__()` method, to prevent it from going to `ModelForm.__init__()` method:

views.py:

```
class PlaceEventFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = PlaceEventForm
    template_name = 'events/event_create.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PlaceEventFormView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PlaceEventFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'place_user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

forms.py:

```
class PlaceEventForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('place_user')
        # now kwargs doesn't contain 'place_user', so we can safely pass it to the base class method
        super(PlaceEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['place'].queryset = Place.objects.filter(created_by=user)
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding how you do this.

Comment: I made the example complete, let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: The `# now kwargs doesn't ... ` comment after the `kwargs.pop('place_user')` is the first time I've ever seen that explained in countless Django Python SO answers! THANK YOU! Super helpful!

Comment: It took me way too long to put this answer together with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400559/2676154) to figure out how to Select a Foreign Key using the authenticated user. Using .initial sounds so basic now (hand/face)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on an iPhone, but do this:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
     form = super(MyView, self).get_form(form_class)
     form.fields['place'].querset = Place....
     return form
```

Wow that was hard! No indention support!

Answer (score 2):

To update Yuji's answer for Django 1.10+ (including Django 2.0+), see the example below (note the updated method signature). Yuji's suggested approach keeps the queryset in the view along with the other business logic, and helps keep any form class extending `models.ModelForm` clean and straightforward.

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = super(MyView, self).get_form()
    form.fields['place'].queryset = Place.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
    return form
```

Shorter:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(MyView, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['place'].queryset = Place.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
    return form
```