# Can I use the current logged in user in models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-contrib

**What I have:**

The default django User model with an attached Profile model that, amongst others, contains a ForeignKey to an Office model. So every user in my application is tied to a specific office.  And in each office there are several Shifts.

*models.py:*

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Office(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='FRA', null=True, unique=True)
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Frankfurt', null=True, unique=True)

class Shift(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="")
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
```

**What I am trying to do:**

Now, in my `CreateView` I want to limit the available choices in the "*shift*" field to the ones attached to the **office of the current logged in user**. I thought about using the `limit_choices_to` option of `ForeignKey`, but I can't get my head around how to access the user information within a model? Something like

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, limit_choices_to={'office': ???})
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="")
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
```

Comment: You can't do this in a model. You would do this in the view. See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47224270/8147165

Comment: Hey, you can write `ModelForm`, pass `request` via `get_form_kwargs()` method to the form, and then filter the field based on user or other field. This is probably what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you both! Got it working in the proposed way of using `get_form_kwargs()`. Sweet!