# Trouble calling the form constructor from django createview

Tags: django, django-forms

I tried to pass the user( i.e, request.user) to my modelform constructor as given in  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806224/sending-request-user-object-to-modelform-from-class-based-generic-view-in-django).But i am getting

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'us'
```

error. Here's my view

```
class dealAdd(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = dealForm
    template_name='deals/deal_Add.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context=super(dealAdd,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        llist=lead.objects.all()
        clist=contacts.objects.all()
        context.update({'leadob':llist,'contob':clist})
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(dealAdd, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'us': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

and my form constructor

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       usr=kwargs.pop('us')
       super(dealForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       print(usr)
      # print(self)
```

the traceback says that i have error at

```
context=super(dealAdd,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

So is there a problem in my view?

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /deals/dealAdd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Sabith\crm1\deals\views.py", line 21, in get_context_data
    context=super(dealAdd,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\CapC\Desktop\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'us'
[06/Oct/2018 15:18:41] "GET /deals/dealAdd HTTP/1.1" 500 91563
```

my form

```
class dealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=deals
        fields= '__all__'
        widgets={
        'refno':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-sm form- 
         control ember-view ember-text-field'}),
        'status':forms.Select(choices=stat,attrs={'class':'btn btn-deals'}),
        'transaction_price':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-sm form- 
         control ember-view ember-text-field'}), 
         'estimated_closing_date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-sm 
         form-control ember-view ember-text-field'}),
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated with the traceback

Comment: can you give your full form?

Comment: @seuling ive added the form.

Comment: @p.ry If you delete the line `usr=kwargs.pop('us')`, error not occurs? And what exactly that line did?

Comment: @seuling get the passed value from kwargs, i think. Got it from the link i've given with the question.

Comment: @p.ry What if you commented out your `get_context_data`? Error not occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the order.

Your CreateView call `get_context_data` first before `get_form_kwargs`. It means it 'pop' your 'us' before it updated it.

Just change `usr=kwargs.pop('us', None)` to avoid error or use `try/except` for it.

Comment: @p.ry What if you remove entire `usr=kwargs.pop('us')` line?