# What is the best way to pass the request variable to the model using CreateView

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on a messaging system where I want to set the originator of the message based on the currently logged in user.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    originator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    destination = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I use a ModelForm and CreateView to represent this:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('destination', 'subject', 'content')
```

So prior to saving this form, `originator` needs to be set to be the currently logged-in user.  I don't think overriding the `save` method of the model is appropriate here, so i was going to do it in the form's `save` method, however I don't have access to the request variable.  In [another CreateView post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773724/how-do-i-use-createview-with-a-modelform/5774124#5774124) the recommendation was to override the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # pass "user" keyword argument with the current user to your form
        kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

However that doesn't work, since you can't actually pass the kwarg `user` to the ModelForm, since ModelForm doesn't accept custom arguments.

What is the best (cleanest and most practical) way to update the `originator` variable with the user information?

Answer (score 3):

In a discussion with [yuji-tomita-tomita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267887/yuji-tomita-tomita) he suggested the following, which I wanted to share:

The first method relies on his original code, sending a `user` kwarg to the form with `get_form_kwargs`, you must then modify your form model similar to this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = self.kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way the original `__init__` function gets the arguments it is expecting.

But the preferred method he suggested was:

```
class MyView(CreateView):

     def form_valid(self, form):
          obj = form.save(commit=False)
          obj.user = self.request.user
          obj.save()
          return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This works really well.  When the `form.save(commit=False)` method executes it populates `self.instance` in the form object with the same instance of the model it is returning to our variable `obj`.  When you update `obj` by executing `obj.user = self.request.user` and save it, the `form` object has a reference to this exact same object, and therefore the `form` object here already is complete.  When you pass it to the original `form_valid` method of `CreateView`, it has all of the data and will be successfully inserted into the database.

If anyone has a different way of doing this I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: I would not call `super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)` as that will save the form again (not necessary). What `form_valid` needs to do is just redirect to the success URL.

Comment: I guess to be safe you'd want to set `self.object = obj` as well, since that is also executed in the `FormMixin.form_valid()` method.  Perhaps a more elegant solution would be to just remove `obj.save()` in the above code, since (as you said) it is saved in the original `form_valid` method.