# How to override form field in CreateView

Tags: django

In model form I can override form field like so

```
class waypointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(waypointForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['waypoints'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Waypoint.objects.filter(user=user))
```

How can I use the same functionality in class based view `CreateView`, so that I can override form field?

I tried `get_form_kwargs` and `get_form` but all in vain. Do I need to create a model form?

Comment: [How do I use CreateView with a ModelForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773724/how-do-i-use-createview-with-a-modelform)

Answer (score 15):

You can override the `get_form_kwargs` and pass the `user` to `kwargs` dictionary. Then in your `__init__()` method, set your field on the form.

**views.py**

Pass the `user` in `kwargs` by overriding the `get_form_kwargs()`.

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):

    form_class = waypointForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user # pass the 'user' in kwargs
        return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

Now, override the `__init__()` method. In that, pop the `user` key from `kwargs` and use that value to create your field.

```
class waypointForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None) # pop the 'user' from kwargs dictionary      
        super(waypointForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['waypoints'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Waypoint.objects.filter(user=user))
```

Answer (score 5):

To use your model form in your view, set `form_class`. In your case, you need to override `get_form_kwargs` as well, so that you can pass `user` to the form.

```
def CreateWaypointView(CreateView):
    ...
    form_class = WaypointForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateWaypointView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```