# Initialize form with request.user in a ModelForm django

Tags: django, modelform

I have this ModelForm

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ['name', 'involved_people',]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['involved_people'].queryset = Profile.objects.exclude(user=user)
```

This is my view

```
def create_schedule(request):
    form = ScheduleForm(request.POST or None)
    schedules = Schedule.objects.all().order_by('deadline_date')

    if form.is_valid():
        schedule = form.save(commit=False)
        schedule.save()

        messages.success(request, "Schedule added successfully!")
        return render(request, 'schedule/index.html', {'schedules': schedules})

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'schedule/create_schedule.html', context)
```

How do you pass  `request.user`  in the view?
How do you initialize the form with `request.user` in it?

Comment: You want the form to be prefilled when the page loads?

Comment: I just want to filter the `involved_people` filled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added `user` to the `__init__` method,

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
```

so now you just pass the user as the first argument when you instantiate your form.

```
form = ScheduleForm(request.user, request.POST or None)
```

Comment: Great answer but in generic views to pass request.user to form I did as below:
```def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AccountSettingsView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs```

and in form:
`self.user = kwargs.get('user')`

Comment: @ShaigKhaligli Either the form should have `def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs)`, in which case you would do `self.user = user`, or the form has `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, in which case you use `self.user = kwargs.pop('user')` so that `user` is removed from `kwargs` before you call `super`. You can see examples of both approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273135/how-to-override-form-field-in-createview)

Comment: yeah brilliant ! i did the same, thanks for helping !