# How to populate(get the data filled) the modelform with the user data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

This is my `models.py`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User_data(models.Model):

    user_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from lrequests.models import User_data

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        fields = ("name", "user_ID")

        model = User_data
```

This is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import UserForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import User_data

def get(request):
    form_class = UserForm
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit = False)
            data.user = request.user
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Sucessfully submitted")
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        return render(request, "request_form.html", {'form' : form_class})

#update
def auto_fill_form(request):
form = UserForm(initial = dict(name = request.user.first_name))
context = dict(form=form)
return render(request, "request_form.html", context)
```

Now, I've tried populating the user data, which was specified whilst creating account. So, that he(user) doesn't tamper the data (as it need to read-only) and it is automatically filled without the user giving the input. I've read django documentation but it specifies only dynamically initialising data
[see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values). I've tried putting that code in the forms.py, but it didn't work.

I've even tried in the HTML template, that didn't work too.

```
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                {{ form.name.errors }}
                {{ form.name.label_tag }} {{ form.name = user.first_name }}
            </div>
            {% comment %} {{ form.as_p }} {% endcomment %}
```

How do I get data by default into the form?
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076529/initialize-form-with-request-user-in-a-modelform-django

Comment: @MohitSolanki  negative!

Comment: What is `{'form' : form_class}`? It should be `{'form' : form}`.

Comment: @hygull `form_class = UserForm` in views.py

Comment: Visiting a page makes GET request to server so else part will be executed where you're creating `form` but you're not using it, why? Please try and let us know. Also have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/. This is for Django 2.1. Based on your Django version you can switch to it by just changing the version in address bar to your.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
else:
    form = UserForm()
    return render(request, "request_form.html", {'form' : form_class})
```

by:

```
else:
    return auto_fill_form(request)
```

Comment: what if I have more fields, which were to be filled manually?

Comment: `NameError: name 'auto_fill_form' is not defined` I didn't find any module to import as well

Comment: Is it a joke? You defined `auto_fill_form` yourself!