# Django QuerySet filtering not working with views, showing blank view even though there are entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am attempting to view a particular set of objects with a certain attribute by using QuerySet filtering, however when I use the filter, the view returns blank. Not sure if I'm using this particular filter wrong, or if I'm calling on the attribute wrong, however I accessed other attributes (as seen below, the attribute "status") and found that it worked fine.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *
from .forms import *



@login_required
def vendorView(request):
    return render(request, 'inv/vendorInventory.html')

@login_required
def consumerView(request):
    return render(request, 'inv/consumerInventory.html')

def unauthenticatedView(request):
    return render(request, 'inv/unauthenticatedInventory.html')
################ need to edit other views to render consumer/vendor/unauth

def display_drinks(request):
    items = Drinks.objects.all()
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'header': 'Drinks',
    }

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        items = Drinks.objects.filter(status='AVAILABLE')
        context = {
            'items': items,
            'header': 'Drinks',
        }
        return render(request, 'inv/unauthenticatedInventory.html', context)

    elif request.user.profile.vendor:
        items = Drinks.objects.filter(donatorID=request.user.username)
        context = {
            'items': items,
            'header': 'Drinks',
        }
        return render(request, 'inv/vendorInventory.html', context)

    elif not request.user.profile.vendor:
        items = Drinks.objects.filter(status='AVAILABLE')
        context = {
            'items': items,
            'header': 'Drinks',
        }
        return render(request, 'inv/consumerInventory.html', context)
```

inventory/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import *



# Create your models here.

class Donation(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, help_text='Describe your donation here')

    choices = ( #for status
        ('AVAILABLE', 'Item ready to be picked up'),
        ('RESERVED', 'Item reserved'),
    )

    expiry = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, help_text="Enter expiration date here")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=choices, default='AVAILABLE')
    misc = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, help_text='Miscellaneous info about your donation')
    donatorID = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = User.username)



    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.description)


class Foods(Donation):
    pass

class Drinks(Donation):
    pass

class MiscObjects(Donation):
    pass
```

As one can see, in models.py, the donatorID is assigned to the Donation object, and is the user's username. In the function display_drinks (in views.py), in the first elif, it should use the user's username to filter whatever items don't have the matching attribute, place items into a QuerySet that do match - however it displays blank, even though there are items that have matching attributes.

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Thanks.

edit: as requested, here's vendorInventory.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block body %}



<center>  <div class="add_buttons">


    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <a href="{% url 'display_foods' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button"> View Food</a>
      <a href="{% url 'add_food' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button"> Add Food</a>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <a href="{% url 'display_drinks' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button">View Drinks</a>
      <a href="{% url 'add_drink' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button"> Add Drink</a>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <a href="{% url 'display_miscObjects' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button"> View Misc</a>
      <a href="{% url 'add_miscObject' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button"> Add Misc</a>
    </div>


  </div>

  </center>

  <div>

    <h4>Currently Viewing {{ header }}</h4>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Expiry Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Misc</th>
        <th>Edit/Delete</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      {% for item in items %}

      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.pk }}
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.expiry }} </td>
        <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.misc }}</td>

        {% if header|lower == "drinks" %}
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_drink' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_drink' item.pk%}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > x </a>
        </td>
        {% elif header|lower == "foods" %}
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_food' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_food' item.pk%}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > x </a>
        </td>
        {% else %}
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_miscObject' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_miscObject' item.pk%}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button" aria-pressed="true" > x </a>
        </td>
        {% endif %}
      </tr>

      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *


class DrinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Drinks
        fields = ('description', 'expiry', 'status', 'misc', 'donator')


class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foods
        fields = ('description', 'expiry', 'status', 'misc')


class MiscObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiscObjects
        fields = ('description', 'expiry', 'status', 'misc')

class ReserveDrinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Drinks
        fields = ('status',)


class ReserveFoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foods
        fields = ('status',)


class ReserveMiscObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiscObjects
        fields = ('status',)
```

Comment: `default = User.username` - this definitely does not work

Comment: NEVER use fields that can change as foreign keys (here `user.username`), and ALWAYS use explicit foreign keys (use a `Models.ForeignKey`).  Note that this is nothing django-specific but really relational model basic stuff.

Comment: How and yes: NEVER use wildcard imports ("from xxx import *") in real-life code either (not even if the module's author says "it's ok" - it's not, definitly). This (mis)feature's use should be restricted to the python shell when you quickly want to test out something. In real code, it will only make your code harder to read, harder to maintain, and prone to unexpected (and not always easy to spot) breakages.

Comment: Can you also post `vendorInventory.html` as this template is specific to the code path with the issue.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've applied an explicit foreign key to the attribute now. It says 'donator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)'.

In my views, the item filter looks like this: '  items = Drinks.objects.filter(donator__username=request.user.username)'.

There are two situations I am running into in forms. A) I don't include 'donator' to be included in the form, and I run into an error saying that donator has been left blank or B) I include 'donator', but when it's displayed on the form it has a dropdown with all usernames, and makes the donator choose his own name.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Ideally, I was hoping for the donator to not have to enter his own name and automatically assign the username to the donation object attribute. Is there a way to do this in views.py or forms.py?

Comment: @WillKeeling added vendorInventory.html, as well as forms.py

Comment: ` Drinks.objects.filter(donator__username=request.user.username)` is wrong, you want ` Drinks.objects.filter(donator=request.user)`. wrt/ your other questions, they all have answers in the doc and on SO, so please do some research first.

Answer (score 1):

replace this in model 
`donatorID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

While saveing the data pass Users Object : `variable_name = User.objects.get(username=request.user)`

Answer (score 1):

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from users.models import *
# or if User model is not overwritten: from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Donation(models.Model):
    choices = (  # for status
        ('AVAILABLE', 'Item ready to be picked up'),
        ('RESERVED', 'Item reserved'),
    )

    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Describe your donation here')
    expiry = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter expiration date here")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=choices, default='AVAILABLE')
    misc = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Miscellaneous info about your donation')
    donator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


class Foods(Donation):
    pass

class Drinks(Donation):
    pass

class MiscObjects(Donation):
    pass


# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from users.models import *
# or if User model is not overwritten: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *
from .forms import *



@login_required
def vendorView(request):
    return render(request, 'inv/vendorInventory.html')

@login_required
def consumerView(request):
    return render(request, 'inv/consumerInventory.html')

def unauthenticatedView(request):
    return render(request, 'inv/unauthenticatedInventory.html')
################ need to edit other views to render consumer/vendor/unauth

def display_drinks(request):
    items = Drinks.objects.all()
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'header': 'Drinks',
    }

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        items = Drinks.objects.filter(status='AVAILABLE')
        context = {
            'items': items,
            'header': 'Drinks',
        }
        return render(request, 'inv/unauthenticatedInventory.html', context)

    elif request.user.profile.vendor:
        items = Drinks.objects.filter(donator__username=request.user.username)
        context = {
            'items': items,
            'header': 'Drinks',
        }
        return render(request, 'inv/vendorInventory.html', context)

    elif not request.user.profile.vendor:
        items = Drinks.objects.filter(status='AVAILABLE')
        context = {
            'items': items,
            'header': 'Drinks',
        }
        return render(request, 'inv/consumerInventory.html', context)
```

**This will work, BUT better to use class-based views here for example:**
official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

# Better naming for model will be a "Drink" instead of "Drinks" (Django code style)
from .models import Drinks


class VendorView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    # better to use 'inv/vendor_inventory.html' naming style for PEP8 compatibility.
    template_name = 'inv/vendorInventory.html'


class ConsumerView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'inv/consumerInventory.html'

# Name for view, I think looks terrible ;)
class UnauthenticatedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'inv/unauthenticatedInventory.html'


class DrinksListView(ListView):
    model = Drinks
    context_object_name = 'items'    # Variable in template, better to use something like: context_object_name = 'drinks'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Drinks.objects.filter(status='AVAILABLE')
        elif self.request.user.profile.vendor:
            return Drinks.objects.filter(donator__username=self.request.user.username)
        # Better to use "else:" here instead of "elif" (for all other logic).
        elif not self.request.user.profile.vendor:
            return Drinks.objects.filter(status='AVAILABLE')
```

**Answers for questions from comments:**

If you want to add automatically user for every new Drinks object, you should do something like this: 
First of all, you should exclude field "donator" in your form:

```
# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #.....
    class Meta: 
        model = Drinks
        exclude = ('donator', )
```

If you use function-based views:
 you should add something like this:

```
# views.py
if request.GET: 
    form = MyForm()
if request.POST:
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        drinks = form.save(commit=False)
        drinks.donator = request.user
        drinks.save()
return render(request, 'my_temlate.html', {'form': form})
```

If you use class-based views: you should overwrite "post" method same way. You can find out more here, also there are examples: [How do I use CreateView with a ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773724/how-do-i-use-createview-with-a-modelform)

Comment: I have to totally disagree with the "better to use class-based views" part - unless you have a need for specialisation (which is actually not the most common case, by far), class-based-views only make simple things MUCH more complicated than they need to be. With all due respect to Django's authors, the decision to force-feed CBVs on users is IMHO one of the most misguided move they made...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. First of all class-based views really make simple things much more complicated, because their main use-case is big projects and big parts of the code , so if you have a code base with 100k+ lines of code which was written using class-based views, it looks more readable and predictably than function-based views code. So function-based views good for simple logic, but in big projects better way will be to use class-based views IMHO.

Comment: I've been using django since the first (0.9.something) public release, I've done literally dozens of (real-life, production) projects with it, the current one being near 500Kloc - is that "big" enough for you ? FWIW I _do_ use CBVs when appropriate (notably for parts of this project - the parts where we do need specialisation). And I maintain that for most cases, CBVs are not only useless but also harmful wrt readability / maintainability. Now I won't go any further about this here (it's getting totally OT) but you can join me in private if you want to discuss this further

Comment: @om2c0de, thanks for your help! I've applied the former code right now, and it comes back with no errors, however it does not assign the user's username as an attribute to the Drink object - it only allows for selection of a username from the tables I have.

Comment: Sounds great! I updated the answer, hope it will help you.